# Obtain the p.m.f. of X

Tags: probability

A string made up of four A’s and six B’s is randomly shuffled. Let X be the number of A’s that appear before the first B.
a) Obtain the p.m.f. of X (5 points) 
[image]

Are those correct and can you explain how should I proceed when tackle such counting problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seek the probability for selecting $k$ from $4$ A-items before the first B, where $k$ may be any integer from $0$ to $4$ inclusive.

So $\binom 4k/\binom {10}k$ is the probability for selecting $k$ from four A-items when selecting $k$ from all ten items.

Also $6/(10-k)$ is the conditional probability that the next item will be one from the six B-items when $k$ A-items have been removed from the ten items.

Thus indeed what you seek is the product of these factors, or any equivalent form.$$\dfrac{4!}{k!~(4-k)!}\cdot\dfrac{k!~(10-k)!}{10!}\cdot\dfrac{6}{(10-k)}$$

Comment: How did we get the other three formulas from this one ?